# Fuzzy EmulateRecognize on Windows Speech Recognition

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, fuzzy-search

Microsoft C# API provide a SpeechRecognitionEngine to recognize Audio stream. One way to test recogition is to call method *SpeechRecognizer.EmulateRecognize*

According to documentation:

```
recognizers ignore case and character width when applying 
grammar rules to the input phrase
```

I'd like to know if there is a way to handle more **fuzzy** string because confidence is very low even for mispelled text ! Far from real life...

- With Audio I could say Hello, Helo, Helllo with a good confidence
- With Text the engine is very strict

EDIT: For what purpose ?

My speech engine is working fine, but I also want to trigger it from text input.

Let's say your on mobile phone and use HTML5 SpeechRecognition. I'd like to send the recognized text to engine to get the same behavior as speech

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're asking for here?  `EmulateRecognize` effectively matches a string against the grammar rules; I wouldn't expect *any* matches for misspelled text.

Comment: Well If I say Hellllo World or Helo World the SpeechEngine will recognize my speech with a strong confidence. If I emulate the same thing with a String the Engine is really strict.

Comment: When you send audio to the recognizer, the SR engine does a lot of work to create a set of phonemes (via acoustic modeling) and then a set of strings (via phoneme modeling).  During that process, much of the ambiguity gets eliminated.  `EmulateRecognize` doesn't generate audio that gets processed via the SR engine; it skips all the modeling and just does a string match.

Comment: Excatly and there is no hack or tricks to workaround this behavior ? (I assume no, but I ask just in case ^^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the answer !
I should better read the documentation !

```
SpeechRecognizer.EmulateRecognize
```

Is really straightforward and test the given string but

```
SpeechRecognizer.SimulateRecognize
```

Will try to build a an ‘idealized’ audio representation of the input phrase (based on the engine's lexicon and acoustic model)

And so it works very well !

Answer (score 0):

When you send audio to the recognizer, the SR engine does a lot of work to create a set of phonemes (via acoustic modeling) and then a set of strings (via phoneme modeling). During that process, much of the ambiguity gets eliminated. `EmulateRecognize` doesn't generate audio that gets processed via the SR engine; it skips all the modeling and just does a string match.

There's no way to work around this that doesn't involve a lot of work (e.g., implementing a SAPI-compatible SR engine that *only* does `EmulateRecognize`).

Answer (score 0):

Enter your string in the SpeechSynthesizer.Speak() and use that as input to SpeechRecognitionEngine?

Comment: Wouhou that's a hack ! I like that even if it's cpu intense :-P